# Apache CXF specify which operations to encrypt / sign

Tags: java, cxf

I am using Apache CXF to implement a SOAP server. It must comply to a standard. The standard specfies that some SOAP operations must be encrypted and signed. Others are unencrypted and not signed.

I am using the interceptor approach (e.g. WSS4JStaxInInterceptor / WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor).

How can you specify which operations shall be unencrypted and the response encrypted and which should not?

Comment: Why are you using the `WSS4JStaxInInterceptor`? Are you ok to use the WSS4JOutInterceptor ?

Comment: Another comment  - please read and follow the [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it may be pretty complex topic. There is god documentation on CXF Security and some [tutorials](https://www.benmccann.com/apache-cxf-tutorial-ws-security-with-spring/). What is not clear exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I must use Stax, as there are hundreds of MB per request and the memory usage would be too much to handle. I did some research but could not find an answer to my question. The question really is how to handle the case when there are some SOAP operations that are secured with WS-Security (Encryption and Signature) and some are not secured (plain). If you have an anwser for the DOM-based Interceptors that might help too and maybe I can adapt it.

Comment: `The standard specfies that some SOAP operations must be encrypted and signed. Others are unencrypted and not signed`   That's not any standard, that's an arbitrary requirement without putting any rationalization for it.

Answer (score 1):

> How can you specify which operations shall be unencrypted and the response encrypted and which should not?

The WSSJ interceptor is assigned for the whole endpoint or client. So if you have some operations which need the security feature and some not, you better split them to separate services / endpoints.

> I must use Stax, as there are hundreds of MB per request and the memory usage would be too much to handle

I personally try to discourage using pure soap for really large payloads, you may still use [attachments along the WSSJ](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/attachments.html)

Another option to pass large content with ensured signing and encryption is using a form of MFT (manged file transfer), e. g. using the OFTP2 protocol. Though this option adds some complexity.

> If you have an anwser for the DOM-based Interceptors that might help too and maybe I can adapt it.

Just read and follow the [documentation](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/using.html) and create a new specific question when something is not clear

This is an example from my project signing the request and expecting signed response

```
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="sixxClientService" 
                     address="${cxf.outbound.sixx.address}" 
                     serviceClass="sixx.clientservice.ClientServicePortType" 
                     bindingId="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"> 
        <cxf:features>
        </cxf:features>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPInInterceptor" />
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/> 
            <ref bean="WSSecuritySixxResponseInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="WSSecuritySixxRequestInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

    <bean id="WSSecuritySixxRequestInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
                <entry key="user" value="sixxkey"/>             <!-- server key alias -->
                <entry key="timeToLive" value="60"/>
                <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="sixxKeystore.properties"/>
                <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
                <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="clients.routes.wssecurity.KeystorePasswordCallback"/>
                <entry key="signatureParts"
                       value="{Element}{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Body;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp"/>
                <entry key="signatureDigestAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <entry key="signatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="WSSecuritySixxResponseInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
                <entry key="user" value="sixxkey"/>             <!-- server key alias -->
                <entry key="timeToLive" value="60"/>
                <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="sixxKeystore.properties"/>
                <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
                <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="clients.routes.wssecurity.KeystorePasswordCallback"/>
                <entry key="signatureDigestAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <entry key="signatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

sixxKeystore.properties:

org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=sixxKeystore.jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=sixxpass
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
```

Edit:

> How can you specify which operations shall be unencrypted and the response encrypted and which should not?

Just an idea - you still can have a reverse proxy or http-route forwarding the request to different endpoints based on SOAPAction or other header.

Comment: This are good advises. Unfortunatly I can't change it, as it is a standard given and there is no option to split it to two endpoints.

Comment: @beat then you need to reconsider the requirement. I mean - the signature is validated and payload is decrypted BEFORE the payload is recognized which operation it is. The interceptor is configured on top of the whole endpoint. Just an idea - you still can have a reverse proxy or http-route forwarding the request to different endpoints based on SOAPAction or other header